# Equations in a table go beyond the page

Tags: tables, equations

I checked several topics regarding tables which go beyond the page. My problem adding to the previous topics is that I am using equations instead of a text. When I try to shorten the subscripts, but it moves the equations forward to the edge not centering them inside. Is there any way to normalize what is in the table to have it fit to the page?

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular} {SS, |1|p{0.8\linewidth}|}   
    \toprule 
    Node & Thermal balance equation \\ 
    \midrule
   1           &$-\frac{k_{glass}~N_{sub}}{D_{glass}} \cdot     (T_1-T_2)-h_{Conv-top}(T_1-T_{Ambient})-h_{Rad-top-sky}(T_1-T_{sky})-h_{Rad-top-ground} (T_1-T_{ground})=0$ \\
   2       & $Q_{glass}+\frac{k_{glass}N_{sub}}{D_{glass}} (T_1-T_2)-\frac{k_{glass}N_{sub}}{D_{glass}} (T_2-T_3)=0$    \\
    3      & $Q_{glass}+\frac{k_{glass}N_{sub}}{D_{glass}} (T_2-T_3)-\frac{k_{glass}N_{sub}}{D_{glass}} (T_3-T_4)=0$   \\
    4-10    & \vdots    \\ 
    11       & $-\frac{k_{Backsheet}~N_{sub}}{D_{Backsheet}} \cdot     (T_{10}-T_{11})-h_{Conv-bottom}(T_{11}-T_{Ambient})-h_{Rad-bottom-sky}(T_{11}-T_{sky})-h_{Rad-bottom-ground} (T_{11}-T_{ground})=0$    \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \caption{Thermal properties of each layers}
    \label{tab: 3-1}
\end{table}
```

This is what I see:
[image]

Comment: the text is simply too wide, you need to decide to make a smaller font or perhaps not use a table format so that the first column couldbe made a heading before each item. Also never do `_{Backsheet}` always `_{\mathrm{Backsheet}}` or `_{\mathit{Backsheet}}` the default math italic font is designed to make adjacent letters not look like a word but a product of variables.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle for the tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you employ a `tabularx` environment that takes up the full width of the text block and which allows automatic line breaking.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Q}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash$\displaystyle}X<{$}}
\newcommand{\vn}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    %\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l Q @{}}
    \toprule
    Node & $Thermal balance equation$ \\
    \midrule
    1&-\frac{k_{\vn{glass}}~N_{\vn{sub}}}{D_{\vn{glass}}} \cdot (T_1-T_2)-h_{\vn{Conv}-\vn{top}}
    (T_1-T_{\vn{Ambient}})
    -h_{\vn{Rad}-\vn{top}-\vn{sky}}(T_1-T_{\vn{sky}})
    -h_{\vn{Rad}-\vn{top}-\vn{ground}} (T_1-T_{\vn{ground}})=0 \\
    2 & Q_{\vn{glass}}+\frac{k_{\vn{glass}}N_{\vn{sub}}}{D_{\vn{glass}}} (T_1-T_2)
        -\frac{k_{\vn{glass}}N_{\vn{sub}}}{D_{\vn{glass}}} (T_2-T_3)=0    \\
    3 & Q_{\vn{glass}}+\frac{k_{\vn{glass}}N_{\vn{sub}}}{D_{\vn{glass}}} (T_2-T_3)
        -\frac{k_{\vn{glass}}N_{\vn{sub}}}{D_{\vn{glass}}} (T_3-T_4)=0   \\
    4--10 & \vdots    \\
    11 & -\frac{k_{\vn{Backsheet}}~N_{\vn{sub}}}{D_{\vn{Backsheet}}} 
         \cdot (T_{10}-T_{11})-h_{\vn{Conv}-\vn{bottom}}(T_{11}-T_{\vn{Ambient}})
         -h_{\vn{Rad}-\vn{bottom}-\vn{sky}}(T_{11}-T_{\vn{sky}})
         -h_{\vn{Rad}-\vn{bottom}-\vn{ground}} (T_{11}-T_{\vn{ground}})=0    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \caption{Thermal properties of each layers}
    \label{tab:3-1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

In your code fragment you have strange column types: `SS,`. If I replace them with `c` I get:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \begin{tabular} {@{} c >{\raggedright\arraybackslash$\displaystyle}p{0.91\linewidth}<{$} @{}}
    \toprule
    Node & \text{Thermal balance equation} \\
    \midrule
1       &   -\frac{k_{\text{glass}} N_{\text{sub}}}{D_{\text{glass}}}     (T_1-T_2)-h_{\text{Conv-top}}(T_1-T_{\text{Ambient}}) - h_{\text{Rad-top-sky}}(T_1-T_{\text{sky}}) - h_{\text{Rad-top-ground}} (T_1-T_{\text{ground}})=0                  
        \\  \addlinespace[9pt]
2       &  Q_{\text{glass}} + \frac{k_{\text{glass}}N_{\text{sub}}}{D_{\text{glass}}} (T_1-T_2)-\frac{k_{\text{glass}}N_{\text{sub}}}{D_{\text{glass}}} (T_2-T_3)=0                         
        \\  \addlinespace[9pt]
3       &   Q_{\text{glass}}+\frac{k_{\text{glass}}N_{\text{sub}}}{D_{\text{glass}}} (T_2-T_3)-\frac{k_{\text{glass}}N_{\text{sub}}}{D_{\text{glass}}} (T_3-T_4)=0                         
        \\[12pt]
4-10    &   \qquad\vdots              
        \\  \addlinespace[9pt]
11      & -\frac{k_{\text{Backsheet}} N_{\text{sub}}}{D_{\text{Backsheet}}}     (T_{10}-T_{11})-h_{\text{Conv-bottom}}(T_{11}-T_{\text{Ambient}})-h_{\text{Rad-bottom-sky}}(T_{11} - T_{\text{sky}}) - h_{\text{Rad-bottom-ground}} (T_{11}-T_{\text{ground}})=0    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \caption{Thermal properties of each layers}
    \label{tab: 3-1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note: for text in variables indices I use `\text` command from amsmath`package. Also some more vertical space betwee rows in table is introduced by`\makegapedcells`from the package`makecells`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and the tips.